# How to configure ESLint auto fix on save in WebStorm/PHPStorm?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, eslint

I am trying to create a custom file watcher in WebStorm that will auto fix ESLint errors on save. In `Settings > Tools > File Watchers` I created a new file watcher with the following settings:

- File type: `Any`
- Scope: `All places`
- Program: `/home/user/Projects/todo-app/eslint-autofix.sh`
- Arguments: blank
- Output paths to refresh: blank
- Other options > Working directory: `/home/user/Projects/todo-app`

**eslint-autofix.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix
```

Then I made an ESLint error and pressed <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> to save. The following error pops up:

```
/home/user/Projects/todo-app/eslint-autofix.sh
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Doesn't built-in ESLint integration work for you? It's under File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint

Comment: It does. But I want to autofix ESLint errors on save so I don't have to run `eslint --fix` manually.

Comment: try starting PhpStorm from terminal - does the problem persist?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On `WebStorm 2020.1.1`, there is a checkbox called `Run eslint --fix on save`.

Also see:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/eslint.html#ws_js_eslint_activate

[image]

Comment: Same settings available in `WebStrom 2020.3.1`. @Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: this not solve the problem

Answer (score 35):

According to [this](https://medium.com/@netczuk/even-faster-code-formatting-using-eslint-22b80d061461) article, settings should be as the following:

- File type: Any (or JavaScript)
- Scope: Project files
- Program: $ProjectFileDir$/node_modules/.bin/eslint
- Arguments: --fix $FilePath$
- Output paths to refresh: $FileDir$

Comment: to avoid absolute path use: $ProjectFileDir$/node_modules/.bin/eslint, and I also recommend to not use the advanced autosave options for linting/prettier (it then reformats while you are still typing) - also be aware that webstorm treats JSX and javascript as different filetypes, and you can only select one file type for the watcher (so i made a duplicate for JavaScript and  React JSX)

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Just to extend on jstice4all's & gotjosh's solution:

I was able to get the FileWatcher to ESLint for some projects, but it wasn't working with the plugin **extends: '@react-native-community'**

```
@react-native-community/eslint-config#overrides[2]:
    Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown
```

Turns out that the **@react-native-community plugin** needs to be ran from the project folder itself in order to load the environment variables, whereas the file watcher runs from the node_module/eslint path. To get it to work I had to add the following config:

- Working Directory: $ProjectFileDir$

[Screenshot Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObKU8.png)

Comment: Good point, thanks. I will update my answer with your solution.